# What is the recommended way of visual testing with Middleman and GitLab CI?

Tags: view, gitlab-ci, middleman, visual-testing, middleman-4

What is the recommended way of visual testing with [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) and GitLab CI?
What is the best way to ensure that code changes are not breaking the views.